# TCP Teardown - Retransmissions

Tags: tcp, firewall, stateful

I am writing a small stateful firewall application as a school project. 
I try to figure out, why my webserver (172.16.0.11) does TCP retransmissions of his FIN+ACK packet.
The first retransmission might be because of the retransmission timeout (the firewall application was quite busy at this time).
I am more interested in the retransmissions at the end. 
From my point of view, the sequence 1635678 was acknowledged by the client (172.16.0.10) in his FIN+ACK (No. 298). 
Why are there retransmissions of the FIN+ACK, even if the sequence was already acknowledged?

Both (client and server) are Debian 8.1 systems, using Iceweasel as browser and Apache as webserver.

Capture at server:
[image: Capture Server]

Capture at client:
[image]